# Intuition behind orthogonal decomposition of $L^2(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral

We are working with the Hilbert space $L^2(\mu)$, such that $\mu(X)<\infty$.

If $M$ is the subspace of constant functions, define $M^\perp$ both formally and "intuitively". (This is a homework problem). My problem is the intuitive description part.

We are told that

$$M := \{g \in L^2(\mu) : g(x) = c \in \mathbb{R}, \ \forall x \in X\}$$
Therefore, if we want the orthogonal complement,

$$M^\perp= \{f \in L^2(\mu) : \langle f,g\rangle=0, g \in M\}$$

Therefore, for any function $f \in M^\perp$, and real constant $c$

$$\langle f, c\rangle = 0 = \int_X cf \ \mathrm{d} \mu = c \int_X f \ \mathrm{d} \mu$$

Thus, it follows that

$$M^\perp = \left\{f \in L^2(\mu) : \int_X f \ \mathrm{d} \mu = 0 \right\}$$

But, I don't understand what would an intuitive definition/description would be in this case.

Comment: How does $\int f =0$ give you $f=0$ a.e. ?

Comment: Oh you're right, that only applies to non-negative functions. I guess I'd need to prove that $\int_A f \ \mathrm{d}\mu$ for every measurable set $A$. Now I am more lost.

Comment: Functions whose average value over X is 0?